# c++11 regex object constructor runtime error

Tags: regex, c++11

I have to generate regex programatically. In this particular case, my regex object should correspond to the string: "([(+1)((+1))])((-1)(+1))*([(-1)((-1))])"

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex r("([(<1)((<1))])((<1)(>1))*([(>1)((>1))])");
    cout << (regex_match("<1>1", r) ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
}
```

However, I am getting the match as false. Are the parenthesis being treated as matchable characters?

I think I have misunderstood regex syntax somewhere. I could not find any helpful material online having complex regex.

PS: I understand that this is a very clumsy regex for this problem. Any leads towards resources for simplifying regex will also be appreciated.

UPDATE: (updated code) https://ideone.com/8HAuEk

Comment: The error message is `prog.cpp:6:31: error: value of type 'regex' (aka 'basic_regex<char>') is not contextually convertible to 'bool'`

Comment: [Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Sorry! I did not compile my code after last-minute editing of code. I have updated the code now.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three issues with your code.

1. [Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).
2. You have an unclosed parenthesis in your code (ironically).

   ```
   cout << (regex_match("+1-1", r ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
   //      ^ here
   ```
3. If we fix that line:

   ```
   cout << (regex_match("+1-1", r) ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
   ```

   we get that runtime error you're asking about. It's caused by `(+1)`. `(+` is a regex syntax error because `+` is a quantifier and can't appear at the beginning of a group. If you want to match it literally, it should be `"(\\+1)"`.

Also, `[(+1)((+1))]` doesn't make much sense. It's equivalent to `[()1+]` and matches a single character that is either `(`, `)`, `+`, or `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
In point 3, why are parenthesis not be used to group the subregex ? My intent is to have <1 ('+' replaced by < to avoid quantifier clash) in the beginning.

Comment: Equivalently, how do I write regex which accepts only two strings ab and cd. I thought it should be [(ab)(cd)]. But it is not working like that in ideone code.